# Can we add tags to the dataframe

Tags: r

Is it possible to get below output

[image]

I tried with below code but was not possible. Can anyone help

```
da <- data.frame(a = c("button","h1"),b = c(tags$button("My header"),tags$h1("My header")))
```

Comment: Where are you trying to display this?

Comment: In R shiny. I am trying to showcase what each is for?